# How to add an Image element for the new PageBuilder content-type in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, page-builder

I have created a new content-type for PageBuilder following the documentation here https://devdocs.magento.com/page-builder/docs/create-custom-content-type/overview.html, the content-type is Example_PageBuilderQuote , however all the elements added in thare textarea, input and select it doesn't show you how to add an image element, I would like to add for example for this PageBuilderQuote module, an image element to show the quote_author_image, but I can't find how to do it in the documentation, can someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the end I checked how it was done in the files:

app/code/Magento/PageBuilder/view/adminhtml/pagebuilder/content_type/image.xml
app/code/Magento/PageBuilder/view/adminhtml/web/template/content-type/image/full-width/master.html
app/code/Magento/PageBuilder/view/adminhtml/ui_component/pagebuilder_image_form.xml

and it worked.

Comment: Hi jose, I am still struggling with this. can you pls help?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please show how you solved this issue? I added the image to new content element for pagebuilder, but the image disappears after the CMS page is saved.