# Custom page builder content type preview.js error

Tags: page-builder, magento2.4.2-p1

I have a custom content type that I want to add an image uploader to. I was able to get the images to upload and display on the frontend. However, when I tried to add code to get the uploader to display in preview.html, I get these errors:

**preview-factory.js:25 TypeError: parts.split is not a function**

**Error within preview component (Vendor_Module/js/content-type/content-type/preview) for content_type. @ content-type-factory.js:70**

I am still fairly new to M2, so I am not sure what I am missing in my custom preview.js file that it doesn't like.

I tried to follow the directions outlined in the Magento 2 documentation for this, but am clearly missing something.

https://devdocs.magento.com/page-builder/docs/content-types/customize/add-image-uploader.html

I also looked at this question in StackExchange to get the images upload to work initially:

[How to add an Image element for the new PageBuilder content-type in Magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287623/how-to-add-an-image-element-for-the-new-pagebuilder-content-type-in-magento2)

/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/content-type/content-type/preview.js:

```
define([
 'Magento_PageBuilder/js/uploader',
 'Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/preview',
], function (PreviewBase, Uploader) {
'use strict';
var $super;

function Preview(parent, config, stageId) {
PreviewBase.call(this, parent, config, stageId);
}

Preview.prototype = Object.create(PreviewBase.prototype);
$super = PreviewBase.prototype;

$super.getUploader = function () {
  var initialImageValue = this.contentType.dataStore
      .get(this.config.additional_data.uploaderConfig.dataScope, "");

  return new Uploader(
      "imageuploader_" + this.contentType.id,
      this.config.additional_data.uploaderConfig,
      this.contentType.id,
      this.contentType.dataStore,
      initialImageValue,
  );
};

return Preview;
});
```

/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/pagebuilder/content_type/content_type.xml

```
<appearances>
    <appearance name="default"
              default="true"
              preview_template="Vendor_Module/content-type/content_type/option-one/preview"
              master_template="Vendor_Module/content-type/content_type/option-one/master"
              reader="Magento_PageBuilder/js/master-format/read/configurable">
        <elements>
            <element name="main">
                <style name="text_align" source="text_align"/>
                <style name="border" source="border_style" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/border-style"/>
                <style name="border_color" source="border_color"/>
                <style name="border_width" source="border_width" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/border-width"/>
                <style name="border_radius" source="border_radius" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/remove-px"/>
                <style name="margins" storage_key="margins_and_padding" reader="Magento_PageBuilder/js/property/margins" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/margins"/>
                <style name="padding" storage_key="margins_and_padding" reader="Magento_PageBuilder/js/property/paddings" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/paddings"/>
                <style name="display" source="display" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/display" preview_converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/preview/display"/>
                <attribute name="name" source="data-content-type"/>
                <attribute name="appearance" source="data-appearance"/>
                <css name="css_classes"/>
            </element>
            <element name="title">
                <style name="text_align" source="text_align"/>
                <html name="title_title" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/html/tag-escaper"/>
            </element>
            <element name="subtitle">
                <style name="text_align" source="text_align"/>
                <html name="title_subtitle" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/html/tag-escaper"/>
            </element>
            <element name="desktop_image">
                    <style name="border" source="border_style" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/border-style"/>
                    <style name="border_color" source="border_color"/>
                    <style name="border_width" source="border_width" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/border-width"/>
                    <style name="border_radius" source="border_radius" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/remove-px"/>
                    <static_style source="max-width" value="100%"/>
                    <static_style source="height" value="auto"/>
                    <attribute name="image" source="src" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/attribute/src" preview_converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/attribute/preview/src"/>
                    <attribute name="alt" source="alt"/>
                    <attribute name="title_attribute" source="title"/>
                </element>
                <element name="mobile_image">
                    <style name="border" source="border_style" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/border-style"/>
                    <style name="border_color" source="border_color"/>
                    <style name="border_width" source="border_width" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/border-width"/>
                    <style name="border_radius" source="border_radius" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/remove-px"/>
                    <static_style source="max-width" value="100%"/>
                    <static_style source="height" value="auto"/>
                    <attribute name="mobile_image" source="src" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/attribute/src" preview_converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/attribute/preview/src"/>
                    <attribute name="alt" source="alt"/>
                    <attribute name="title_attribute" source="title"/>
                </element>
        </elements>
    </appearance>
</appearances>
<additional_data>
    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="isShowImageUploadInstructions" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        <item name="isShowImageUploadOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="maxFileSize" xsi:type="object">ImageMaxFileSizeDesktop</item>
        <item name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="string">jpg jpeg gif png</item>
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_PageBuilder/js/form/element/image-uploader</item>
        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">imageUploader</item>
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">background_image</item>
        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">imageUploader</item>
        <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="url" xsi:type="object">Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Config\ContentType\AdditionalData\Provider\Uploader\SaveUrl</item>
        </item>
        <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_PageBuilder/form/element/uploader/preview</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_PageBuilder/form/element/uploader/preview/image</item>
        <item name="mediaGallery" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="openDialogUrl" xsi:type="object">Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Config\ContentType\AdditionalData\Provider\Uploader\OpenDialogUrl</item>
            <item name="openDialogTitle" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Insert Images...</item>
            <item name="initialOpenSubpath" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
            <item name="storeId" xsi:type="object">Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Config\ContentType\AdditionalData\Provider\StoreId</item>
        </item>
        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</additional_data>
```

/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/pagebuilder_content_type_form.xml

```
<fieldset name="general" sortOrder="20">
    <settings>
        <label/>
    </settings>
    <field name="title_title" sortOrder="10" formElement="input">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <dataScope>title_title</dataScope>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Title</label>
        </settings>
    </field>
    <field name="title_subtitle" sortOrder="40" formElement="input">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <dataScope>title_subtitle</dataScope>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="false">Subtitle</label>
        </settings>
    </field>
    <field name="image" formElement="imageUploader">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Image</label>
            <componentType>imageUploader</componentType>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <imageUploader>
                <settings>
                    <allowedExtensions>jpg jpeg gif png</allowedExtensions>
                    <maxFileSize>4194304</maxFileSize>
                    <uploaderConfig>
                        <param xsi:type="string" name="url">pagebuilder/contenttype/image_upload</param>
                    </uploaderConfig>
                    
<previewTmpl>Magento_PageBuilder/form/element/uploader/preview</previewTmpl>
                </settings>
            </imageUploader>
        </formElements>
    </field>
    <field name="mobile_image" formElement="imageUploader">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Mobile Image</label>
            <componentType>imageUploader</componentType>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <imageUploader>
                <settings>
                    <allowedExtensions>jpg jpeg gif png</allowedExtensions>
                    <maxFileSize>2097152</maxFileSize>
                    <uploaderConfig>
                        <param xsi:type="string" name="url">pagebuilder/contenttype/image_upload</param>
                    </uploaderConfig>
                    <previewTmpl>Magento_PageBuilder/form/element/uploader/preview</previewTmpl>
                </settings>
            </imageUploader>
        </formElements>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/template/content-type/content_type/option-one/preview.html

```
<div attr="data.main.attributes"
ko-style="data.main.style"
class="pagebuilder-content-type title-section one pagebuilder-image type-nested"
css="data.main.css"
event="{ mouseover: onMouseOver, mouseout: onMouseOut }, mouseoverBubble: false">
<render args="getOptions().template" />
<figure attr="data.main.attributes" ko-style="Object.assign({}, data.main.style(), !data.desktop_image.attributes().src ? {} : {borderStyle: 'none'})" css="data.main.css">
    <scope args="getUploader().getUiComponent()">
        <render />
    </scope>
    <img if="getViewportImageData().attributes().src"
         attr="getViewportImageData().attributes"
         class="preview-image"
         css="getViewportImageData().css"
         ko-style="getViewportImageData().style" />
    <figcaption if="data.caption.html()"
                attr="data.caption.attributes"
                css="data.caption.css"
                html="data.caption.html"
                ko-style="data.caption.style">
    </figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to modify my preview.js file and resolve this issue. I looked at the Magento Page Builder examples to modify it.

https://github.com/magento-devdocs/pagebuilder-examples/blob/master/Quote/Custom/view/adminhtml/web/js/content-type/custom-quote/preview.js

Here is what my preview.js file looks like now:

```
define([
  'Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/preview',
  'Magento_PageBuilder/js/uploader'
], function (
  PreviewBase, 
  Uploader
) {
    'use strict';

    function Preview(parent, config, stageId) {
      PreviewBase.call(this, parent, config, stageId);
    }

  var $super = PreviewBase.prototype;

  Preview.prototype = Object.create(PreviewBase.prototype);

  Preview.prototype.getUploader = function() {
    var initialImageValue = this.contentType.dataStore.get(
      this.config.additional_data.uploaderConfig.dataScope,
      ""
    );

    return new Uploader(
      "imageuploader_" + this.contentType.id,
      this.config.additional_data.uploaderConfig,
      this.contentType.id,
      this.contentType.dataStore,
      initialImageValue
    );
  };   

  Preview.prototype.getViewportImageData = function getViewportImageData() {
    var desktopImageData = this.data.right_desktop_image;
    var mobileImageData = this.data.right_mobile_image;
    return this.viewport() === "mobile" && typeof mobileImageData !== "undefined" ? mobileImageData : desktopImageData;
  }
  
  return Preview;
 });
```